# Can't remove optional("String"). states its non-optional

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm working on a spendings tracker app. All the logic is now working, but when I want to display transaction data in a UILable, it displays it as       `optional("String")`

I have looked around the Internet and have tried unwrapping the string in 2 different ways, but I'm not able to fix it.

Adding an ! to the end of the string gives an error `Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type "String"`

Here is the code I'm using now that displays `optional("String")`

**Here I set up my struct and array**

```
struct Transaction {
    var discr = ""
    var amount = 0
}
var transactions = [Transaction]()
```

**This is how I add data to the array**

```
transactions.append(Transaction( discr: String(describing: transDescrInput.text), amount: Int(tempAmount)))
```

**This is how I display the data in a tableview**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = transTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sCell")
    let discrText = transactions[indexPath.row].discr.uppercased()
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "€\(transactions[indexPath.row].amount)"
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(discrText)"

return cell!

}
```

**This is how it shows up in the app**

[Iphone simulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0xac.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is already where you add data to the array.
Assuming that `transDescrInput.text` is an optional string,

```
String(describing: transDescrInput.text)
```

returns a *non-optional* string `"Optional(text...)"` and there is 
no sensible way to revert that. You should use optional binding
or other unwrapping mechanisms instead, for example

```
if let text = transDescrInput.text {
    transactions.append(Transaction(discr: text, amount: Int(tempAmount)))
}
```

or with nil-coalescing:

```
transactions.append(Transaction(discr: transDescrInput.text ?? "", amount: Int(tempAmount)))
```

As a rule of thumb, `String(describing:)` almost *never* the correct
solution (even if the compiler suggest it as a Fix-it), it only hides
the actual problem.

Answer (score -1):

Right after posting this post I realised I have to unwrap the text before I add it to my array. So I changed the way I save the string:

```
transactions.append(Transaction( discr: String(describing: transDescrInput.text!), amount: Int(tempAmount)))
```

I added an ! behind the transDescrInput.text to unwrap it before I save it to my array.

Comment: better to do String(describing: transDescrInput.text ?? "") to avoid force unwrap

Comment: You should not force unwrap it. What if it were an empty textField? The app would surely crash

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio Even more important is to *not* use `String(describing:)` at all.

Comment: @Moritz: I once thought of posting a Q&A *"String(describing:) considered harmful"*  :)

Answer (score -2):

May I suggest do something like this?

```
let discrText = transactions[indexPath.row].discr.uppercased()
cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(discrText!)"
```